# Classification with frequency feature vector produces poor results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm classifying data into 2 classes, by Logistic Regression from python scikit-learn.

I'm trying different types of feature vectors:

- Binary
- Frequency
- TF-IDF

In Binary and TF-IDF feature vectors, I get great results. However, in Frequency feature vectors, I get poor results unless I multiply the values by some factor (for example 10, or 100). The multiplication improves the results significantly (the higher the factor, the better).

Is this a normal behavior or is it more likely that I'm doing something wrong? I suspected that the values are too small and my array rounded some of them down to zero because its type was merely `float` (unspecified bits number). But I tried changing it to `np.float64`, and the results didn't change.

What other factors can be causing this?

---

**Edit: Learning Curves:**

**Binary | TF-IDF | Frequency X 10 (from left to right):**

[image: binary_tfidf_freq10]

**Normal frequency (3 attempts):**
[image: frequency]

---

**Edit 2: (data and code)**

Frequency Data: X axis: a dictionary of 1K words , Y axis: 1K samples - 500 each class
[image: feature_vector]

Labels (1K binary labels):
*note that it's a transpose vector. so X here is the samples*
[image: labels]

Code for frequency:

```
#loop...
vec[i] = np.divide(sample_vals, len(sample.split()))
```

Code for frequency X 10:

```
#loop...
vec[i] = np.multiply(np.divide(sample_vals, len(sample.split())), 10)
```

Classification code:

```
#in `X` I have the data, and in `y` I have the labels
scores = [clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).score(X[test], y[test])
          for train, test in kfold.split(X)]
```

Comment: Can you show all your [learning curves](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Learning_Curves)? I suspect it is just a question of optimization (step size, iterations). Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Emre Thank you! I added learning curves. Please take a look

Comment: Your small frequency plots have not converged. What happens after a few thousand iterations? Are you persisting the loss only once every 200 iterations; why is it piecewise linear?

Comment: Do you mean if I add more training examples? If so then I get [this plot](http://imgur.com/a/ATy8p)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by persisting the loss. But I think you mean why do I have results only every 200 examples on the plot. I'm using [this function to draw](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html). Maybe I need to play with the parameters...

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/PUW6vkH) it's 100 instead of 200 (note that the `x` axis is number of training examples, not iterations)

Comment: @Emre Can you conclude anything from the charts? Thanks

Comment: Not to explain why multiplying the feature vector by a scalar makes a difference, because it should not. Can you share your data and code?

Comment: @Emre Added data and code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved if I let [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) do the job:

```
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=dictionaryList, use_idf=False)
final_vec = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(df[DF_X_DATA])
```

`use_idf=False` is the solution. It lets it calculate frequency automatically. I don't have to manually divide by the sample's length this way.

The results now are ~90% and the learning curve looks normal.